# Access 2003 is not showing Database Diagram option

Tags: ms-access, database-diagramming

So I have this project on access 2003. I am trying to create a relation diagram of the tables. I have found this webpage of Microsoft: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-database-diagram-adp-HP003085405.aspx but I do not see any Database diagram option as I was supposed to see according to that article.

I am not even sure what they meant by Diagram window (I can see the list of tables, forms, queries and so on in a window, is that what they meant?). I have worked with DB diagram in access 2007 and 2010 but 2003 seems to be totally different.

And another question: is there any restriction in creating diagram on front-end/back-end application?

Comment: but do we know if this is an ADP project? The fact of someone referencing some help is no indication of this being an ADP project. The text referencing the concept of creating the diagram in the front end or back end suggests this has nothing to do with SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was fairly simple. I just had to double click on my mdb file then hold down the shift key. That made the options visible. The rest was easy.

Sorry my question might not be clear. I saw one answer but I think that is too advanced for me to even understand.

Answer (score 0):

That article is referring to what is called an ADP project. An ADP project is a specialized type of Access database that ONLY works with SQL server. Thus the article you reference would not apply to creating regular Access databases (that are not working with SQL server). Perhaps you can clear up if you are in fact using an ADP (Access Data Project). From your description it sounds like you are not.

As for the locating where you build the diagram and setup relatonahsips, it always in the back end (or the "same" database). I mean you could not have 5 different front ends link to a back each with different relationships settings. So the actually physical mdb (or accdb) file is where the relationships are setup and other systems from Excel, word or even a MS Access front end can only link to that data file – not set up relationships.

As for the diagram option missing? You should find the option under the menu option

Tools->relationships